# Is binary isomorphic to decimal representation?

Tags: abstract-algebra, number-theory, group-isomorphism

My friend and I were just talking about whether decimal representation isomorphic to binary one. He said that it is true since there is a obvious 1-1 relationship between them. But how about  0.999999.....and 1 converted to binary? 1 is going to be 1. 0.999999... is going to be 0.111111111....but it would have a 0 at least, after infinite many 1? Does that equals to 0.11111111.....? I am not sure about that, though I think for any e>0, the difference between these two number will be

Comment: What's "isomorphic" when talking about bases?

Comment: I mean there exits an metamorphism that is one to one, onto and operation preserving.

Answer (score 3):

The idea of a $0$ "after" infinitely many $1's$ does not make sense. The number $1$ has two decimal representations in any base you are working in. In binary, you can use either $1$ or the infinite sequences of $1's$ ($0.111\dots$) to represent the number $1$. As for calling your observation an isomorphism, that is not really an appropriate use of that word. I'd say something along the lines of "there is a bijection between the set of real numbers in decimal base and the set of real numbers in binary base."

Comment: very correct. One remark is that you (namely OP) must not confuse the real numbers (which is an abstract structure) and any particular way to representing real numbers. Using any base expansion is just a way to represent numbers. If you have two systems to represent numbers then of course you have a metamorphism from one to the other. It's just the identity.

Comment: Sorry for the misunderstanding. So it is not appropriate to call it isomorphic, is it because, even using different number bases, we are just talking real numbers, which is the same group? And for isomorphic, we need to talk about two different groups?

Comment: For this question I would stay away from thinking of $\Bbb{R}$ as a group, unless of course you are doing algebra. First and foremost, $\Bbb{R}$ is a set, and as such, it is (generally) spoken of in terms of injections, bijections, etc. To speak of $\Bbb{R}$ as a group you will also need to consider what operation makes it a group. To say one thing is isomorphic to another is to say that the two sets, along with their respective group operations are in essence "of the same structure." The notion of structure and group operations is not needed to answer the question you posted.

Comment: I still didn't get it. Why we prefer bijection instead of isomophic?

Comment: The implications of isomorphic are completely overkill for this type of question. It's like using a cannon to kill a bird.